# Joomla k2 url static timestamp

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-k2

I'm using Joomla 2.5 with K2,

In category/item URL there is always static time-stamp "2012-12-25-22-22-08" like:

/site/2012-12-25-22-22-08/test-item

I tried some solutions like make sure there is no menu have that time-stamp as external URL, and categories/items also don't have it on aliases..

Any idea how to remove it from URL?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you have any menu items with type: `System Links -> External Url`.

Sometimes alias is being added from these items (try to switch it to something else and the alias will be appeared).

If not please check all your menu items and k2 categories alias to find the item that is adding this value.

> Τhere is also good to follow these steps:
>
> - Clear your joomla cache
> - Clear your browser cache
> - Clear sessions mysql table (via phpmyadmin)
> - Check if your .htaccess is being altered

Good Luck!